# Nested object in Mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

After playing around with GraphQL, I am trying to dig a little deeper.

I managed to work a mutation with a simple object but as soon as I try with a nested object it does not work.

I am trying to get an object looking like this:

{
  id,
  name: {
    first,
    last
  },
  contacts: {
    phone,
    email
  },
  ...
}

Here is my code:

schema.js:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import resolvers from './resolvers';

const typeDefs= [`
    type Name {
      first: String
      last: String
    }
    type Contacts {
      phone: String
      email: String
    }
    type Education {
      school: String
      graduation: Date
    }
    type Internship {
      duration: Int
      startDate: Date
    }
    type Applicant{
      id: String
      name: Name
      education: Education
      internship: Internship
      contacts: Contacts
    }
    type Query {
      allApplicants(searchTerm: String): [Applicant]
    }
    type Mutation {
      addApplicant(name: Name!, education: Education!, internship: Internship, contacts: Contacts): Applicant
    }
  `];

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

export default schema
```

resolver.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';
import applicantModel from './models/applicant';
import technologyModel from './models/technology';
import companyModel from './models/company';


const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allApplicants:(root,{searchTerm}) => {
      if (searchTerm !== '') {
        return applicantModel.find({$text: {$search: searchTerm}}).sort({lastName: 'asc'})
      } else {
        return applicantModel.find().sort({lastName: 'asc'})
      }
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    addApplicant: (root,{name:{first, last}, contacts:{email, phone},education: {school},internship: {duration, startDate} }) => {
      const applicant = new applicantModel({name: {first: first, last: last} , contacts:{ email: email, phone: phone}, education: {school: school} , internship: {duration: duration ,startDate: new Date(startDate)}})
      return applicant.save();
    }
  }
}

export default resolvers;
```

I keep getting the error
*"Error: The type of Mutation.addApplicant(name:) must be Input Type but got: Name!."*   or, if I change the type from "type" to "input" in schema.js I get 
*"Error: The type of Mutation.addApplicant(name:) must be Output Type but got: Name!."*

I am obviously missing something !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `input` for mutation rather than type like

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import resolvers from './resolvers';

const typeDefs= [`
    type Name {
      first: String
      last: String
    }
    input NameInput {
      first: String
      last: String
    }
    type Contacts {
      phone: String
      email: String
    }
    input ContactsInput {
      phone: String
      email: String
    }
    type Education {
      school: String
      graduation: Date
    }
    input EducationInput {
      school: String
      graduation: Date
    }
    type Internship {
      duration: Int
      startDate: Date
    }
    input InternshipInput {
      duration: Int
      startDate: Date
    }
    type Applicant{
      id: String
      name: Name
      education: Education
      internship: Internship
      contacts: Contacts
    }
    type Query {
      allApplicants(searchTerm: String): [Applicant]
    }
    type Mutation {
      addApplicant(name: NameInput!, education: EducationInput!, internship: InternshipInput, contacts: ContactsInput): Applicant
    }
  `];

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

export default schema
```

Comment: I tried, I get the error Error: The type of Applicant.name must be Output Type but got: Name

Comment: updated code, we need to different name as well like type is Name and input is NameInput

Comment: Thank you ! I did not understand that I neede both the Input AND the type